# Chaincode Query Transcation is not executing in EC2 Insance

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

[please find the image first intsertion was happened sucessfully.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdP8U.jpg)I am trying to query my transaction in Amazon-EC2 but it is returning NULL with endorsement failure even though my insertion transaction is working fine in the local system.

This is the error I get:

```
endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"transaction returned with failure: Error: {\"Error\":\"candidate does not exist with: 13VV1A0533\"}"
```

Comment: firstly, can u upload ur full terminal result, a bit unclear~ then there was error in invoke file, 13VV1A0533, check for the certificates' location folder....

Comment: You need to provide waaaay more information and context, if you expect other to be able to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

From the error it seems that the chaincode is missing error handling for scheduleInterview method.

What the error means is that there is no data for the key candidate id.

Do revert if this doesnt help.